# Prove that, if $n$ is a positive integer then $n^5$ and $n$ have the same last digit

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I know that the same digit meant $\mod 10$

---

So, $n^5$ congruence $n (\mod 10)$

And $a^p$ congruence $a (\mod p)$

But I don’t know how to make it continue.
Thanks for all answer

Comment: Try for $m \in \{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$.  Now consider $n=10k+m$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It follows from $n^5\equiv n\pmod2$ and $n^5\equiv n\pmod5$ that $n^5\equiv n\pmod{10}$.

(From Fermat's little theorem, $n^5\equiv n\pmod5$,

and $n^2\equiv n\pmod2$, so by induction $n^k\equiv n\pmod 2$.)

Answer (score 0):

Using Euler's theorem $a^\varphi(10)\equiv 1\mod 10$ assuming that $(a,10)=1$, that's how you get your result if if the last digit is either, $1$, $3$, $7$ or $9$. If the last digit is either $0$ or $5$, the resut is obvious, as being a multiple of $10$ won't change by raising it to a power, same with being an odd multiple of $5$. Then, you just check the classes for $2^5,$ $4^5$ and $6^5$.

$$2^5\equiv 32\equiv 2$$
$$4^5\equiv 32^2\equiv 2^2\equiv 4$$
$$6^5\equiv 2^5\cdot3^5\equiv 2\cdot 3\equiv 6$$

Comment: what if the last digit is $8$?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner I absolutely forgot, but you just have to notice that $8\equiv -2$ and then you're done

Answer (score 0):

HINT.- And this is so for $n$ and $n^{1+4k}$ and for $n^2$ and $n^{2+4k}$ and for $n^3$ and $n^{3+4k}$ and $n^4$ and $n^{4k}$ ($k$ natural,$k\ne0$ in this last case).